# Visualforce Error - Select components should have at least one child component of type selectOption or selectOptions

Tags: visualforce-component

```
<apex:page >
  <apex:sectionHeader title="Student" subtitle="New Student" help="/apex/page"/>
   <apex:form >
     <apex:pageBlock title="Student">
       <apex:pageBlockButtons location="Top">
         <apex:commandButton value="Register"/> 
          <apex:commandButton value="cancel"/> 
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>  
              <apex:pageBlockSection title="Basic Information">
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                  <apex:outputLabel value="Lastname">
                     <apex:inputText/>  
                  </apex:outputLabel>        
                 </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                 <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                  <apex:outputLabel value="Phone">
                     <apex:inputText/>  
                  </apex:outputLabel>        
                 </apex:pageBlockSectionItem> 
                 <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                  <apex:outputLabel value="Firstname">
                     <apex:inputText/>  
                  </apex:outputLabel>        
                 </apex:pageBlockSectionItem> 
                  <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                  <apex:outputLabel value="Email">
                     <apex:inputText/>  
                  </apex:outputLabel>        
                 </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                  </apex:pageBlockSection>                 
                <apex:pageBlockSection title="Communication Details">
                   <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                   <apex:outputLabel value="city">
    <apex:selectList size="1" style="width=160px;red;background:yellow">
  <apex:selectOption itemLabel="-none-" itemValue="-none-"/>
  <apex:selectOption itemLabel="vijayawada" itemValue="vijayawada"/>    
  <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Guntur" itemValue="Guntur"/>
  <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Madanapalle" itemValue="Madanapalle"/>
                       </apex:selectList>      
                       </apex:outputLabel>
                    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <apex:outputLabel value="Gender">
                     <apex:selectRadio>
     <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Male" itemValue="Male"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Female" itemvalue="female"/> 
                        </apex:selectRadio>   
                   </apex:outputLabel>
                    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <apex:outputLabel value="place">
                        <apex:inputText/>  
                         </apex:outputLabel>
                    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <apex:outputLabel value="Languages">
                       <apex:selectCheckboxes>
                        <apex:selectList>
           <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Telugu" itemValue="Telugu"/>
           <apex:selectOption itemlabel="English" itemvalue="English"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemlabel="Tamil" itemvalue="Tamil"/>
                           </apex:selectList>
                       </apex:selectCheckboxes>
                     </apex:outputLabel>
                 </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>   
              </apex:pageBlockSection>

       </apex:pageBlock>   
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have nested an `<apex:selectList>` inside an `<apex:selectCheckboxes>`.

```
                   <apex:selectCheckboxes>
                    <apex:selectList>
       <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Telugu" itemValue="Telugu"/>
       <apex:selectOption itemlabel="English" itemvalue="English"/>
        <apex:selectOption itemlabel="Tamil" itemvalue="Tamil"/>
                       </apex:selectList>
                   </apex:selectCheckboxes>
```

You should remove one of these select components, since you can't nest them like that, and include the select options as direct children of the remaining component.

Comment: @Hemanth - mark the answer as resolved, will help others